# Swift declaring array of multiple optional type to Any not work as expected

Tags: swift, types, type-conversion, type-inference, anyobject

I used `Any` type to store array of multiple optional type with default value, and got unexpected result.

```swift
let i64: Int64? = nil

print([
    i64 ?? 0,
    i64 ?? 0,
    i64 ?? 0
])
```

Then, `[Optional(0), 0, 0]` is printed.

Following is my detailed experiment. First, I declared the following variables:

```swift
let i64: Int64? = nil
let i32: Int32? = nil
let i: Int? = nil
let str: String? = nil
```

Then I put some of these variables into an `Array` and assigned to `Any` type.

```swift
var any: Any

any = [
    i64 ?? 0,
    i64 ?? 0,
    i64 ?? 0
]
print(any)                    // [0, Optional(0), 0]
print(type(of: any))          // Array<Any>
```

It's weird that one of the value is `Optional(0)` and others retained `0`. And the position of that optional variable are not always located at the same index, it's placed randomly.

This situation occurred only if size of array is 3 or greater, array with 2 elements worked as expected.

```swift
any = [
    i64 ?? 0,
    i64 ?? 0
]
print(any)                    // [0, 0]
print(type(of: any))          // Array<Int64>

any = [
    i64 ?? 0,
    str ?? ""
]
print(any)                    // [0, ""]
print(type(of: any))          // Array<Any>
```

And I found that if I specified the type of those default value, it seems worked perfectly.

```swift
any = [
    i64 ?? Int64(0),
    i64 ?? Int64(0),
    i64 ?? Int64(0)
]
print(any)                    // [0, 0, 0]
print(type(of: any))          // Array<Int64>

any = [
    i64 ?? Int64(0),
    i64 ?? Int64(0),
    i64 ?? Int64(0),
    str ?? ""
]
print(any)                    // [0, 0, 0, ""]
print(type(of: any))          // Array<Any>
```

However, I couldn't conclude with a good explanation why this can work.

In my opinion, `i64 ?? 0` should always considered `0` as same type of `i64`, which is `Int64`. It comes from the following assignment test:

```swift
let test1 = i64 ?? 0
print(type(of: test1))        // Int64
let test2 = i64 ?? Int64(0)
print(type(of: test2))        // Int64
let test3 = i64 ?? Int32(0)   // compiled error
```

But why `i64 ?? 0` value in Array act different to `i64 ?? Int64(0)`?

Should I really need to specify the type of `0` in every assign operation? Is any way to make the array works as expected without the `Int64(0)` type conversion.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your issue.  What version of Xcode are you using and what is your macOS version?

Comment: Not an answer, but even if you're going to ultimately assign your array to an variable of  type `Any`, you should still use `as [Int64]` to  both speed up compilation, and to make the type information more clear in this context, which can clearly be a little ambiguous at times.

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for your reminder! Actually, I'm making a JSON-like data structure but not only a simple array. In other words, I have this problem when I tried to use `Dictionary<String, Any>` type, and the value field of dictionary  (`Any` type) could be Boolean, Int, Array or another Dictionary. I simplify the problem to a single Array and make it reproducible so you guys can check this easier. Any suggestions to my implementation of JSON-like Dictionary are also welcome.

Comment: @vacawama I'm using Xcode 12.5 (12E262) on macOS 11.3 (20E232). Thanks for your advice, I didn't think it might be a compiler problem. I tried it on some online Swift playground and it seems work well. Maybe it's a Swift compiler issue, can I have your Xcode version?